# Texture doen't show correct after origin change in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In my case, I have multi planes with same texture. After I join that together or change origin(but origin to geometry is OK), the texture show incorrectly.
It's only happen in EEVEE, when I switch CYCLE everything is fine.
I'm not sure this is a bug or not. Anyone know what cause this situation and how could I avoid this.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix weird clipping glitch on my Object with Image Texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235412/how-do-i-fix-weird-clipping-glitch-on-my-object-with-image-texture)

Comment: I need join those planes together, change the blend mode to alpha clip will lose some details of image edge.

Comment: I see. But this is the answer due to current limitations. You are going to have to keep meshes, or use alpha clip or hashed